# SOAP Spring wsdl link

Tags: java, spring, soap

I have an endpoint in Spring application

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service.GetCountryRequest;
import io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service.GetCountryResponse;

@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service";


    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CountryEndpoint(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
        GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
        response.setCountry(countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName()));

        return response;
    }
}
```

and WebService config

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "countries")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
    }
}
```

I'm running this as a spring boot application using embeded tomcat server and it starts up fine

I also have a test which passes fine

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014-2015 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package hello;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service.GetCountryRequest;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.WebIntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
public class ApplicationTests {

    private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port = 0;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan(ClassUtils.getPackageName(GetCountryRequest.class));
        marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendAndReceive() {
        GetCountryRequest request = new GetCountryRequest();
        request.setName("Spain");
        assertNotNull(new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller).marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:"
                + port + "/ws", request));
    }

}
```

now I want to get wsdl to be able to make a client. I already tried many links but all of them do not work. does anybody can advise something?

Comment: I used example from this link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the WSDL will be available under `http://<host>:<port>/ws/countries.wsdl`.
for eg

> http://localhost:8080/ws/countries.wsdl